# .NET C# UDP SNMP Socket Bug

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, snmp

I'm creating four sockets on a computer with four network adapters and binding each socket to one network adapter.

> Network Adapter 1 is at 192.168.100.10. Socket 1 binds to Network Adapter 1
>    Network Adapter 2 is at 192.168.100.20. Socket 2 binds to Network Adapter 2
>    Network Adapter 3 is at 192.168.100.30. Socket 3 binds to Network Adapter 3
>    Network Adapter 4 is at 192.168.100.40. Socket 4 binds to Network Adapter 4

Below is the code I use:

```
Socket _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localIP, 0);
EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)ipEndPoint;
```

Each network adapter has a local network with one different device at IP 192.168.100.1. I send SNMP (UDP protocol) request data to this device.

> Socket 1 sends data to device 1 (192.168.100.1) while binded to 192.168.100.10 Network Adapter 1
>    Socket 2 sends data to device 2 (192.168.100.1) while binded to 192.168.100.20 Network Adapter 2
>    Socket 3 sends data to device 3 (192.168.100.1) while binded to 192.168.100.30 Network Adapter 3
>    Socket 4 sends data to device 4 (192.168.100.1) while binded to 192.168.100.40 Network Adapter 4

```
EndPoint remote = (EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(peer.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork ?    IPAddress.Any : IPAddress.IPv6Any,0);

IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_localIP, 0);
EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)ipEndPoint;
_socket.Bind(ep);

byte[] inbuffer = new byte[64 * 1024]; 
_socket.SendTo(buffer, bufferLength, SocketFlags.None, (EndPoint)netPeer); //bufer has the  snmp   request
Thread.Sleep(4000);
if (_socket.Available &gt; 0)
{
  recv = _socket.ReceiveFrom(inbuffer, ref remote);
}
_socket.Close();
```

The above code is created in four threads and each socket is always sending and receiving data. After sending one data request and response the socket gets closed. A new one is created for the next SNMP request. Socket blocking is true. TTL is 128 by default.

This works for 90% of the SNMP requests, however for one particular set of SNMP requests (10%) I see that the SNMP `_socket.Available` always returns 0. The crazy thing is that I can see the SNMP respsonse come back in Wireshark. I do see the response in Wireshark and there is no difference in the raw Wireshark data when `_socket.Available > 0` or `_socket.Available == 0`. These 10% of SNMP requests do work sometimes but not all the time. I do see the same data in Wireshark both times.

I've tried a lot of troubleshooting, but the bottom line is that I see the data response in Wireshark but the code still shows `_socket.Available == 0`. I was thinking that maybe one of the other sockets is stealing the data? Is that possible even though the socket is binding to another network card?

I also tried the below code where I ignored the `_socket.Available` and use timeouts instead of sleeping. I get the same result.

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_localIP, 0);
EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)ipEndPoint;
_socket.Bind(ep);
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, timeout);
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, timeout);
_socket.SendTo(buffer, bufferLength, SocketFlags.None, (EndPoint)netPeer);
recv = _socket.ReceiveFrom(inbuffer, ref remote);
```

I was going to have only one socket run at a single time, but that will slow down the program.

I was also going to try two sockets, one for send and one for receive, to see if it fixes it.

Any ideas? I'm actually using a lot of the code in SnmpSharpNet library. Please let me know if you have any insight into this issue or any suggestions.

Comment: It is critical that you receive your packets in timely manner with UDP to clear the receive buffer, or you may get drops due to full buffers.

Comment: What's the value of _socket.ReceiveBufferSize? Is it large enough for your data? Default value 8192 bytes.

Comment: My socket buffer size was set 1024*16 bytes. Data usually comes in at 128 bytes or so .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be a routing issue because the PC was getting confused because of similar networks being on the the other end.

Answer (score 0):

It is critical that you receive your packets in timely manner with UDP to clear the receive buffer, or you may get drops due to full buffers. It is possible to flood the receive buffer if you aren't reading them out fast enough. 10% drop rate sounds like a lot, but that may be due to your code.

In your code I see Thread.Sleep(4000)

You should make sure a packet doesn't wait in the receive buffer. Sleeping for 4 seconds is a bit much. Its been years since I did much TCP/UDP coding, but I remember enough to know that I had the best results with UDP when I used a separate thread per receiver, and blocked on the read, that way the OS was responsible for waking my thread immediately when data was ready.

At minimum, lower the Thread.Sleep(4000) down to something sub-second (try 250 or less) and see if it improves. If it does, you are on the right track. It is possible to increase the OS level receive buffer size, but this is usually only for extreme cases, and shouldn't need to be done if your user code is written well.

Also, I see no reason to open/close sockets continually. Keep it open.

Comment: This code should work but same results.No sleeps here. My timeouts are 4000 seconds though but it should trigger asap?         IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_localIP, 0);
EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)ipEndPoint;
_socket.Bind(ep);
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, timeout);
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, timeout);
_socket.SendTo(buffer, bufferLength, SocketFlags.None, (EndPoint)netPeer);
recv = _socket.ReceiveFrom(inbuffer, ref remote);